# Caffeine and creatine

Tags: supplements, creatine, caffeine

I have read from a number of online sources that creatine isn't as effective when taken with caffeine.

I also read that if you space out the caffeine consumption from the creatine consumption, it may be OK.

My question is: is it OK to take caffeine and creatine on the same day, as long as we have some gap between the two? If so, what's a safe gap?

**UPDATE:** Here's one of the sources I remember I read about it - http://examine.com/faq/does-caffeine-counteract-creatine.html

Comment: I think the examine.com link you posted sums it up pretty nicely.

Comment: A lot of preworkout supplements have both creatine and caffeine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ever you read, you can take creatine whenever you feel more comfortable.
I have taken it in the mornings, and now i take it after workouts, because of bro science.
At the end of the day, my results are the same with it.

I have also taken a scoop of creatine(when i first started) and a cup of coffee before my work outs and i saw and felt the creatine working, meaning, you should not worry about it too much.
It is important not to over think things like this, keeps away the stress.

Just space them out if it makes you feel more comfortable, but from my experience, it is not important.

Comment: More likely you got the benefits of the coffee, and previous creatine supplementation. You will not feel immediate effects from ingested creatine.

Comment: This seems very reasonable and it is what I am doing. 

I also really like the advices given by the Muscle for Life website (http://muscleforlife.com). 

In one article (http://www.muscleforlife.com/how-to-take-workout-supplements/) he cites a study that indicates that taking creating _AFTER_ workout is more effective. Here's the article: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23919405.

Comment: @JohnP i have never said that it was immediate, i have been taking creatine for over a year now. I have even done the creatine loading, which is actually bs.
And by the benefits i observed were my gains on creatine vs my gains without it.

Comment: @kolrie Different bodies will probably respond differently, i am taking it after because of rumors. I always took it in the mornings but since i started intermediate fasting i moved it to after workout.